# Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, xcode6, alamofire

When I try to run my iOS App in Xcode in app:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/78CC9A04-53B7-49D3-9E4D-7DF0CAA41DD0/Sawasdee.app/Sawasdee
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

What should i do?

Comment: I recommend you add the tag for alamofire to your question

Comment: I have same problem but I don't think alamofire has anything to do with it since problem occurs even after removing alamofire, then it just shows another module in same error. The problem is with AdHoc provisioning profile but I haven't found a solution for it.

Comment: I am having this problem when I added a new scheme. The original scheme seems to work fine, only the new one has the issue.

Comment: I had the same problem. All I had to do was uncheck the "copy only when installing" box, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how you have your project set up, it's difficult to give exact advice. The first thing you should do is checkout out the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) of Alamofire. It has great explanations for manual set up, CocoaPods and Carthage. You should most likely be able to solve your problem that way.

If you still cannot figure it out, then let me take a guess. You're obviously not using CocoaPods, so you are either using Carthage or manual installation. Either way, you certainly need to `Embed Binary` as @Dato' pointed out. The other thing you may have missed is that you need to `Embed Framework` so that the dyld can pick up the Alamofire.framework at runtime.

[image: Embed Frameworks]

Hopefully that helps shed some light. If it doesn't, please provide some additional information to give us a better context.

Comment: Hi @asiandudeCom, did the end up solving your issue? If yes, would you mind upvoting and marking as the answer?

Comment: The Carthage doc doesn't mention where the `Cartfile` should be placed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set here

[image]

and here

[image]

Comment: Done it but it doesn't fix error. In facts, it produce more error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to link all your dependencies as static libraries rather than frameworks (for example, if you're using Cocoapods you can remove use_frameworks! from your Podfile), that should fix the issue for now.
check below link for more details
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051#issuecomment-580139830