# Cocoapods frameworks appearing in red, not loading in ad-hoc distribution

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire, swifty-json

I am using Cocoapods for my app and I am getting the following error when running on a real device:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/ACBD6627-6548-41A8-A48E-4A9B763E20E7/MyAppSupport.app/MyAppSupport
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/ACBD6627-6548-41A8-A48E-4A9B763E20E7/MyAppSupport.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: mmap() error 1 at address=0x10012C000, size=0x0005C000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/ACBD6627-6548-41A8-A48E-4A9B763E20E7/MyAppSupport.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Dyld Version: 353.12
```

It works fine on the simulator, but I am confused. Here is what my Pods looks like in the sidebar:

## [image]

All the frameworks are red. Any help on fixing this crash would greatly help. I believe it has something to do with those above frameworks not properly loading.

Comment: try these links may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000990/library-not-loaded-rpath-alamofire-framework-alamofire, https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/101

Comment: Thanks but I have already looked at them

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26024100/)".