# Cocoapods: dyld library not loaded

Tags: swift, cocoapods, dyld, command-line-tool

So since a few days I have this issue: I create an empty command line project and set up Cocoapods, but then I always get this runtime error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Versions/A/Alamofire
Referenced from: /Users/...
  Reason: image not found
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

This happens regardless of the pod I want to use and also in already existing projects. Windowed Cocoa applications and iOS apps are not affected. I tried setting the pods.framework to Optional as suggested elsewhere, but this doesn't help. I tried it with the newest Cocoapods beta and the stable release and reinstalled Xcode, but without success. I noticed under Build Phases there is no 'Embed Cocoapods framework' as usual, so I tried adding that manually; didn't work either.

I've run out of ideas, so does anybody have any idea what might cause this? Otherwise I'll file a bug report. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this behaviour is expected, as there is no easy way (for CP) to link libraries to a command line tool.

Comment: Im having the same issue as well.. how did you solve it?

Comment: same problem im facing :(

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: suspense :P :P :P :P :P

Comment: xcode v8 requires sierra and hence try updating to sierra. that should do the magic

Comment: and also include Alamofire in EmbeddedLibraries as well,

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000990/library-not-loaded-rpath-alamofire-framework-alamofire